# Removing View from its superview getting a bad access error XCODE

Tags: objective-c, uiview

since the release of the storyboard it has been a long time since I've used addSubview and removeFromSuperview. Obviously I have forgotten how to use them.

So on my UIViewControllerA I have this code for a button:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {

    dyf_FacebookViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Facebook"];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

}
```

Which loads a UIView that is handled by UIViewControllerB. now this view can be called by many different ViewControllers to be a subview, which is why I have it remove itself from the superview.

So on UIViewControllerB I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {

     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Unfortunately that returns with a bad access error. Please help!

Thanks

- Michael

EDIT:

The subview added (subview's viewcontroller) will be in control for removing itself as it is in control of the button on the subview. So I do not have access to the original controller.view variable as that is in ViewControllerA

Comment: The question no one is asking is why are you instantiating a view controller if you are only adding it's main view to the current controller? Unless u have very specific reasons to do so, this is a big mistake and has been covered extensively in recent WWDC talks. If you are working with view controller containment you need to read more about it because you are doing it wrong. Finally a view cannot have two superviews so when you add B view to A controller, B controller does not have that view set anymore so when you call it to remove the view, bad things will happen as you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep a reference to your dyf_FacebookViewController object, so you can do the following:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

What you're doing now is to remove your main view from its superview, which can have serious consequences, giving you a bad access.

Comment: right, but like I said, the close button code is kept in a different ViewController. so I would have to have access to the controller.view variable, could I pass it?

Comment: You could implement a delegate mechanism, so UIViewControllerA would know when the close needs to happen. You can do the same thing via NSNotificationCenter. Also, maybe you should use UIViewController container APIs to have a safer implementation.

Comment: I'm probably going to setup a delegate. I am not sure why I didn't think of that before. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case there is a better way to do this, I'm not going to vote best answer at this moment. I'm going to give it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the view you added, then keep a copy of the view controller...

```
// in this VC.m
@interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) dyf_FacebookViewController *dyfController;
@end

- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {

    self.dyfController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Facebook"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.dyfController.view];
}
```

Later, to close the view...

```
[self.dyfController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: I don't have access to controller.view in the other view controller though. so how could I pass it to the new view controller which is handling the view added.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([controller.view superView]) {
    [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```